# I want to upgrade my samsung s3 mini sd card

Tags: samsung-galaxy-mini

How do i change the sdcard without losing all my games pictures ect and does every thing on the phone on on the chip or do you need to do something to put it all on the chip (YES im thick when it comes to phones LOL thankyou paula

Answer (score 0):

Just copy all your data from your previous SD card to your newer SD card. Everything would work fine if nothing is left behind.